# Docker Volumes on Mac with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, docker-volume

I'm attempting to run the following command on Mac OSX:

```
docker run --rm --name kong-database \
    --network=kong-net \
    -v /Volumes/docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
    -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
    postgres:9.6
```

With the intention that it will launch postgres in in a docker container, and persist the database data on my local file system in `/Volumes/docker/postgres`. However, I get the following error, and the container fails to run:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
```

Any idea what I can do to get this going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that `/Volumes` was owned by `root`. When I switched this to something like `/Users/JoshuaErney/Volumes`, this ran successfully. Here's an example:

```
docker run --rm --name kong-database \
    --network=kong-net \
    -v /Users/JoshuaErney/Volumes/docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
    -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
    postgres:9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by jerney is correct, here is what it looks like with docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  test-postgres-compose :
    ...
    volumes :
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
...
volumes :
  pgdata :
```

[Docker compose volumes info](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)